# Return only last batch in TRY..CATCH

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, try-catch

I have some SQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @RowsInserted int;
    SET @RowsInserted = @@ROWCOUNT;
    SELECT @RowsInserted+'test' as [SUCCESS];
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH    
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ERROR]    
END CATCH
```

To my surprise, this actually produces two batches (data sets):

[image]

I can't use `GO` to split the batches due to the way `TRY...CATCH` works.  So does that mean there's always some dummy result set if there's some error caught?

What I'd really like to do is throw away the SUCCESS batch (or other dummy batches like this when caught).  Otherwise I'd have to navigate through some garbage batches to find the Error reporting batch in the catch statement which seems confusing.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do in the catch block is *raise* an error rather than *selecting* it.

```
BEGIN CATCH
    -- rethrow error
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

There's a separation there: result sets (`select`) are ment for data, while errors (`raiserror`) are ment to communicate failures.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why there's so many [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) of `TRY...CATCH` that use `select` in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible - the reference to the resultset is returned to the client before the enumeration begins and before it's possible to know that any record evaluation will produce an error.